# pytest-bdd page object implementation

Tags: python, selenium, pageobjects, pytest-bdd

I am new to pytest-bdd. I have to implement the automation framework from the scratch. SO I have followed some material and implemented with small framework very basic. When I run the test I can see webdriver is not getting started at all and I don't see any error. I am not sure how to fix this issue. Could anyone help me what is the root cause of the issue I need some examples with pytest-bdd page object model implementation?

** My project structure**
[![projectstructure][1]][1]

Inside the tests directory I have features and step_def directory is there. Inside the steps_def I have a test_file_name.py and init file is there.

Inside the page objects directory I have basepage and loginpage python file is there

**Basepage.py**

```
"""
Base page which has base URL and locators and parent class for other classes

"""
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class Base_Page:
    "Base page which has locators and URL"
    def __init__(self,driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def do_click(self,by_locator):
        WebDriverWait(self.driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(by_locator)).click()

    def do_send_keys(self,by_locator,text):
        WebDriverWait(self.driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(by_locator)).send_keys(text
```

**Loginpage**

```
"""
Login page actions
"""
from page_objects.base_page import Base_Page 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from config import config

class Login_page(Base_Page):
    "Class to run the login page"
    user_name = (By.XPATH,"//input[@id='username']")
    password = (By.XPATH,"//input[@id='password']")
    check_box = (By.NAME,"remember")
    login_button = (By.XPATH,"//input[@id='login']")
    base_url = config.BASE_URL
  
    
    def set_username(self):
        "Set the username in the username field"
        try:
            username = self.do_send_keys(self.user_name,"1111111")
            self.result_flag = True
        except Exception as e:
            self.result_flag = False
            print(f"Could not set the username. Got an error {e}")
        
        return self.result_flag
```

**Conftest**

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from pytest_bdd import given

@pytest.fixture(params=['Chrome','Firefox'], scope="class")
def init_driver(request):
    if request.param == 'Chrome':
        web_driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    if request.param == 'Firefox':
        web_driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    request.cls_driver = web_driver
    yield 
    web_driver.close()

@given('Navigate to the URL')
def navigate_url(init_driver):
    "Pass the username"
    init_driver.get("https://www.example.com")
```

my test file which is inside the step_defs

```
from pytest_bdd import given, when, then, scenario, parsers
from page_objects.base_page import Base_Page
from page_objects.login_page import Login_page
import pytest



scenario("../features/login.feature",'Login to the app')
def test_pass():
    pass


@when(parsers.cfparse('Enter the username {username:Number}',extra_types=dict(Number=int)))
def get_username(init_driver):
    "Set the phone number as a username"
    log = Login_page(init_driver)
    log.set_username()
```

**My feature file**
'''
Feature: Navigate to the Practo app and Login with credentials

Scenario Outline: Login to the app
Given Navigate to the URL
When Enter the username ''
And ENter the password
And De-select the checkbox
And Click the login button
Then Verify we have logged into the app

```
When I run pytest test_file_name.py I am not getting any error but it's not starting the webdriver also ,it just gives collected 1 item and it's passed. 


can someone help me how to fix this issue?


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnA6C.png
```

Comment: Hey, I am working with Selenium webdrivers with Python, but using Python behave. I have never encountered an isssue like this. Using Pytest are you able to launch a browser first ? have you passed in the PATH for the webdriver? i dont see that in your code.

Comment: No I am not able to launch the browser. I am not passing the path for the webdriver. is it necessary to do it?

Comment: I have included the geckodriver/chrome executable path then also the browser is not getting instantiated.

Comment: yes, you have to. without access to a webdriver, how do you expect an instance of a webrowser to automatically open?. I shall post an answer on how to get it to open a browser, please go through it and get back to me if any doubts

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = "Path to geckodriver")
driver.get("https://google.com")
time.sleep(10)
driver.close()
```

Comment: make sure path to geckodriver is also added as a environment variable

Comment: I did what you have  mentioned but I am facing the same issue

Comment: did you run the above code in a seperate window ?

Comment: I did what you have mentioned but I am facing the same issue => what is the issue please post a screenshot

Comment: When I run the test there is no error and I can see test is passed 100%. But the browser itself is not getting started. I can say that test is showing passed without running.

Comment: Ok see ... i have sent you some code, create a new tester.py file and paste my code there, run it and attach a screenshot of that in your question. otherwise i dont even know what you are doing.

Comment: I am not interested in the test code. jsut run the above code i have sent